# Is it fine to add a log statement inside a property setter?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I've a class that has a property that should not contain a value beyond a certain maximum.

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    private int adjustedInt;

    public int NotGreaterThanFifty
    {
        get => this.adjustedInt;
        set
        {
            this.adjustedInt = value < 50 ? value : 50;
        }
    }
}
```

We wanted to log all instances where the property was tried to get assigned a value greater than 50. I added a log in a business class that assigns value to this property. This covers the majority of the cases. But there are few rare instances where the same property could be set. I got feedback asking why don't we add log in the property setter.

It sounded very odd to have a log statement inside a setter. Is it good practice?

Comment: If you log in a property setter depending on the execution path that can be log flood. 
If it is only rarely set this might be ok. But the core of the problem is that you dont know who sets the property and what values they provided. 

You could make the property private and build. Then the compiler should show you all references to the property. If that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not unheard of, I've seen this done before.
IMO, If your class already have the logger as a dependency, then there's nothing wrong with this kind of thing. After all, one of the points of exposing a property instead of just a field is to allow logic when setting (or in some weird cases, even in getting) the underlying value. If you want to keep track of that logic, it stands to reason to use a logger in your property setter.
However, if that's the only reason for your class to use a logger, I would consider having the property as a public get/private set property and have it set using a method that can return an indication of the value that was set, or even some message saying what went wrong - something like

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
      public int NotGreaterThanFifty { get; private set; }

      public string TrySetNotGreaterThanFifty(int value)
      {
          var result = "";
          if(value > 50) {
              result = "Can't set value to more than 50";
              value = 50;
          }
          NotGreaterThanFifty = value;
          return result;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do in a situation where i dont now all instances where the property was tried to get assigned a value greater than 50.

I would introduce a second property NotGreaterThanFiftySave and check all references to NotGreaterThanFifty one by one. If i confirmed the value was legit from this caller i let them call NotGreaterThanFiftySave instead.

This way you have less callers on NotGreaterThanFifty. You could also make the property Obsolete

```
  private int adjustedInt;

  [Obsolete("Callers have to be checked")]
  public int NotGreaterThanFifty
  {
        get => this.adjustedInt;
        set
        {
            Log.Error("invalid caller");
            this.adjustedInt = value < 50 ? value : 50;
        }

  }

  private int adjustedIntSave;

  public int NotGreaterThanFiftySave
  {
     get => this.adjustedInt;
     set
     {
        this.adjustedIntSave = value < 50 ? value : 50;
     }

  }
```

when you are done you can delete NotGreaterThanFiftySave an have all callers checked.